# Is there a way to programmatically display the inverse of a hex color using CSS?

Tags: css, background-color

For example my footer color is this:

```
.footer {
    background-color: #808080;
}
```

On hover, I want to display the inverse color?

```
.footer:hover {
    background-color: inverse color!?;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Side note: there is no need to indent *and* use `>` for code.

Comment: You should search for "css invert color". The first search result explains all.

Comment: define `opposite color` ? i never heard about this, i know invert and other filter

Comment: TemaniAfif i do not know, how i know what is that what i want to leran, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invert the color like this:

```
 .footer {
    background-color: #808080;
 }
 .footer:hover { 
    background-color: #808080;
    -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
    filter: invert(100%);
 }
```